# With a bot, how do I avoid or handle IRC server MOTD's?

Tags: networking, python, irc, protocol, bots

I have an IRC bot written in Python that works fairly well. I think the issue is with my limited knowledge of the IRC protocol, so IRC gurus are particularly welcome here :D

When you first connect to an IRC network,  a MOTD usually gets displayed. The network will not accept any commands until the MOTD is finished. So with my bot, I have to have a loop that checks for the end of the MOTD. This isn't particularly modular at all, as in my experience not all servers end their MOTD's the same way. Is there a way to tell the server to not send the MOTD, or indeed a better way to wait for the end of the MOTD to tell the server what channel I wish to connect to?

My current code for waiting for the end of MOTD consists of a while loop reading the input buffer and parsing each full command into a list. It takes this list and searches each string object for a certain string that appears at the end of FreeNode's MOTD, if it is found, the loop ends and a command to join a channel is sent before going into the main loop.

Is there a better way to handle the MOTD's? I can't help but feel that this way is rather clumsy.

Comment: I don't know python or any IRC stuff however I imagine you could just have it wait 10 seconds or something before it activates.

Comment: You don't have to wait for the MOTD to be finished to start sending commands. You will just get the results later.

Comment: @chipperyman573 I've thought of that, but it rubs me the wrong way to rely on a timer for authentication. To my mind, it can cause as many issues, with regards to modularity, as my current setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell the server to not send the MOTD, or indeed a better way to wait for the end of the MOTD to tell the server what channel I wish to connect to

No, there isn't a way to turn off the MOTD. However, it shouldn't even be necessary, because your assumption that "The network will not accept any commands until the MOTD is finished" is not true in the first place.

All networks start accepting commands *immediately* as soon as you register (i.e. send `NICK` and `USER`) – some of them merely delay *acting on* those commands by a second or two. **It is perfectly valid to start sending commands as soon as you can.**

---

In any case, you wouldn't need to delay the main loop to achieve this – indeed, *all* received input should be handled by the same loop. Instead, you would just keep track of whether you have already seen an "end of MOTD" line, and send the `JOIN`s the first time you see it.

Also, from your description, it does sound like you're using a somewhat unreliable method to detect the end of MOTD. If you're looking for the "End of /MOTD" string – don't. Instead, parse the entire line as specified in [RFC 1459 § 2.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459#section-2.3.1) (here's a not-particularly-Pythonic [parser](https://github.com/grawity/code/blob/master/lib/python/nullroute/irc.py)) and check the *command* in each line, since the descriptive text can vary between different IRC daemons. You should also check for the "no /MOTD" message.

For example, you would have:

```
# raw input is ":leguin.freenode.net 376 grawity :End of /MOTD.\r\n"
# split input is [":leguin.freenode.net", "376", "grawity", "End of /MOTD."]
# parsed input is {"prefix":  "leguin.freenode.net",
#                  "command": "376",
#                  "args":    ["grawity", "End of /MOTD."]}

RPL_WELCOME   = "001"
RPL_ENDOFMOTD = "376"
ERR_NOMOTD    = "422"

if not sent_initial_join:
    if command in {RPL_WELCOME, RPL_ENDOFMOTD, ERR_NOMOTD}:
        conn.send("JOIN %s\r\n" % ",".join(channels))
        sent_initial_join = True
```

But as said above, this should never be necessary. Just send the `JOIN`s immediately after `NICK`, `USER`, and things like `CAP END`.

And by the gods, do *not* use something as silly as a 10 second timeout for this.

Comment: Thank you. The statement regarding the network not accepting channel join commands before the end of the MOTD was based off of my own experience when writing this bot. I was unable to get it to join the channel, unless I waited for the server to finish talking.

I am entirely aware of how bad my current setup is, which is why I am looking for a better way of dealing with it. Similarly I am aware of the flaws of the 10 second timeout.

Thank you for the link, that should help me to make the bot much more portable :D

Comment: @LiamMeron That's probably due to some kind of bug in your bot, such as assuming that a particular message must be a reply to a particular command.

Comment: The freenode servers are configured to delay responses until 1-2 seconds after the MOTD, but they *do* always send the responses; I have tested this.

Comment: Yup, y'all are right! I just re-wrote the necessary parts of the code to just go ahead and send the JOIN command, and it works. I dunno what  the bug was, but I guess the fact that it now works renders my question fairly moot. However, I still learned something, so as a friend says, "Time is never wasted, so long as something is learned." Thanks!

Comment: some [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2969441/1986995) say we need to wait and others, like yours, say that we don't.

Comment: @freeforalltousez: That answer is wrong. If you do what its second paragraph says, you won't be able to connect to half the networks _at all_, because their ircds won't realize you're connected until _you_ send some data. _(They use a feature called "deferred accept"; it serves as protection against some attacks.)_ Some don't even _have_ anything to send; the initial notices are just courtesy information about slow checks, and I've seen networks that don't do such checks, therefore they don't send any greeting either.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is wait until I get an 376 or 422 numeric then I send the commands to join channels, setup notify list, etc.

```
if split_line[1] == '376' or split_line[1] == "422":
    # End of /motd # keep track if it is the first motd 
    # (on connect) or already connected.
    if not socket_data.state[client_socket]['connected']:
        socket_data.state[client_socket]['connected'] = time()
        # Join channels now
```

An irc server sends messages starting with an number either as the first word or the second word following ":irc.server.com". I just check if the first character of the line is not ':' then I add an empty string to the split_line. If the second word is an digit then it is an numeric. Different numbers mean different things, in this case, just looking for 422 will tell you there is no MOTD file, and 376 says end of MOTD and 375 is the content of the MOTD. https://www.tg007.net/raws lists many raw numeric codes.